# CSP settings for Quantcast

Tags: javascript, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am integrating in my website the Quantcast script for tracking audiences. When the page loads in the browser I get the error below. I know that is a script encoded as base64 but how do I allow it to execute using the CSP and CORS headers?

> Refused to load the script
>   'data:application/javascript;base64,ZnVuY3Rpb24gcXVhbnRzZXJ2ZSgpe30='
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.cloudflare.com
>   *.quantserve.com".

Here is my headers:

```
headers {
    contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self' *.cloudflare.com *.quantserve.com;"
    contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" img-src 'self' *.fbcdn.net *.twimg.com *.googleusercontent.com *.xingassets.com *.vk.com *.yimg.com secure.gravatar.com *.stuffpoint.com *.pixabay.com;"
    contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.googleapis.com edge.quantserve.com;;"
    contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com;"
    contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.cloudflare.com *.quantserve.com;"
    contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" connect-src 'self' twitter.com *.xing.com;"
    contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" frame-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' edge.quantserve.com;"
}
```

Comment: CORS isn’t relevant at all to the message cited in the question. That message is strictly about CSP only.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data:` to the `script-src` line.

```
contentSecurityPolicy = ${play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy}" script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: *.cloudflare.com *.quantserve.com;"
```

Note: This generally has some security implications but your `script-src` is so permissive that it offers pretty much no protection anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle this would be to place it inside a file instead of using inline inside  tag.. due to the security concerns from allowing `unsafe-inline`